# How to fill right side of screen CSS?

Tags: css

I am making a webpage, and currently, my background looks like this:

```html
<body id="bg" style="padding: 2%; background: linear-gradient(#e66465, #9198e5); height: 100%; background-repeat: repeat-y; background-size: 50% auto;">
</body>
```

It fills the left side of the screen, right?
But I need it to fill the right side.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Remove the `background-size: 50% auto;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it by using the `CSS` property `background-position`:

```css
body {
  padding: 2%; 
  background: linear-gradient(#e66465, #9198e5); 
  height: 100%; 
  background-repeat: repeat-y;
  background-size: 50% auto;
  background-position: right;
  
}
```

```html
<body id="bg">
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add `background-position: right;` to your CSS.

```html
<body id="bg" style="padding: 2%; background: linear-gradient(#e66465, #9198e5); height: 100%; background-repeat: repeat-y; background-size: 50% auto; background-position: right;">
</body>
```